# While calling haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml it is throwing an error in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, haar-classifier

I am constantly getting an error on this. I have seen all the relevant queries and all of them have resolved but mine is not..

```
face_xml = r'C:\Users\abdul\Desktop\Haar Cascade github\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
mouth_xml = r'C:\Users\abdul\Desktop\opencv project\Face Mask Detection\haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml'
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(face_xml)
mouth_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + mouth_xml)
mouths = mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 10)
```

Now the error says

```
----> 1 mouths = mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 10)

error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'
```

I have checked my file path, I tried by putting the xml file in the same directory but this error is not ready to go out.

I'll really appreciate your time and patience for this

Comment: The error is not related to the XML file, but the image file. The image file which you are using in the function `mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale` is not read correctly. Check the path of the image in the `cv2.imread` function and verify it by printing out or displaying the image using `cv2.imshow('image',gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

Comment: @ArjunMuraleedharan First of alI I want to appreciate your efforts for the solution and really thanks for this. I have tried the `cv2.imshow` method , and I am able to get the image but the error is not getting out.

Comment: The `error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty()` normally happens when the image or in your case, `gray` is not empty which can happen because of multiple reasons including, not reading the image correctly or a faulty image. Can you update the question with the part where you load the image also?

Comment: @ArjunMuraleedharan If the image file was not read correctly, the error was thrown in `face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(face_xml)` statement.

Comment: @AbdulTaufiq I don't believe there is a problem in image reading. Did you download the haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml other than opencv repo?

Comment: @AhmetTavli the error has occurred in the `mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 10)` lline, because the error says `cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale`, from the c++ function right?

Comment: @ArjunMuraleedharan Yes you are definitely right and this is indeed a strange problem.

Comment: @AhmetTavli yes dear, I have downloaded it from somewhere else's git hub page. It is well working with the other cascade xml files but the problem is with this particular xml file. I tried with other mouth detecting cascade files but the error has been stick with feviquick glue.